# Html Button that calls JQuery and does not post back

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to have a button that doesn't post back to the server, and the click event can be detected by jquery? I have an MVC page that takes a while to load and access a database and i just want to reduce the number of loads required and db hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make the button a regular button instead of a `submit` button, and then do:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    whatever it is I want to do ...
});
```

Comment: This is the answer im looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can have attach any behavior you want using jQuery.

Here's your button

```
<button class="my-button">click this</button>
```

Here's your jQuery

```
$("button.my-button").click(function(){
  // do something!
});
```

If you'd like to use the submit button on the form, here's a more **unobtrusive** way:

```
$("#some-form input:submit").click(function(){
  // do something special!

  // prevent default behavior of button
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the button with `<input type="submit">` it will submit the form to the server;
but if you use `<input type="button">` , it will not, and you can detect the onclick event

Comment: You can still use `<input type="submit" />` and use unobtrusive javascript to alter the behavior of the button. See my answer for details.

Comment: Oh, yes, I know that .. But I think it's simpler to set the type to "button"

Comment: I think you might be missing the point. If someone doesn't have javascript enabled, you still want the form to work. Every form needs to have at least one `type="submit"` button.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect click event of button using jquery.

Give and id to that button , call  function with that id on click event.

```
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
// call ajax here

.post()  // ajax call

or

.get()   // ajax call


});
```

Make combination of Jquery ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: he specifically said he doesn't want to make additional requests to the server. How does `$.post` or `$.get` help with that?